# In SQL Server, convert 'mmmm dd,yyy' string to datetime format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, how do I convert a string of type '`MMMM DD,YYYY`' (i.e. `June 01, 2013`) to a regular datetime type (`20130601`)?

As far as I know, `Convert()` only works to convert dates into strings, not the other way around.  I'm sure there's a standardized answer somewhere, but I can't find one for SQL Server. Should I write a custom procedure to parse the string?

Comment: I just tried `select cast('June 01, 2013' as datetime)` and it worked. Might be locale dependant or something.

Comment: Why don't you fix the source to send proper, non-regionalized and unambiguous formats in the first place?

Comment: Why did I not see that? Zespri, post that as an answer and you got another green check!

Comment: @Aaron, that would be best, but it's coming from a client.

Comment: According to the documentation, `convert()` works in both directions. See the footnote in the header of the last column of the large table listing the styles in this documentation which states "output when you convert to character data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not recommended to store your date in string formats, you still could properly convert string to date. When you know exact format, avoid using `cast` and use `convert` - see possible formats [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

```
set language english
select convert(datetime, 'June 01, 2013', 107)

-----------------------
2013-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

Conversion from and to 107 format depends on your connection settings. If, for example, your connection language is not english, you could get an error

```
set language norwegian
select convert(datetime, 'June 01, 2013', 107)

-----------------------
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```